# Travis CI + Go: can't build

Tags: go, compilation, travis-ci

My [.travis.yml](https://github.com/weldpua2008/deployer/blob/master/.travis.yml) is:

```
language: go
go:
  - 1.5
install:
  - go get github.com/tools/godep
  - godep restore
branches:
  only:
  - master
script:
  - go build  example/myproduct/deployer/deployer.go
notifications:
  email: false
```

And [it failed](https://travis-ci.org/weldpua2008/deployer/builds/130099695) with this error:

```
go build  example/myproduct/deployer/deployer.go    
go install command-line-arguments: build output "deployer" already exists and is a directory    
The command "go build  example/myproduct/deployer/deployer.go" exited with 1.    
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

I have [VagrantFile where it's ok](https://github.com/weldpua2008/deployer/blob/master/Vagrantfile#L7):

```
go get github.com/tools/godep
cd /opt/gopath/src/github.com/dorzheh/deployer
godep restore
ln -s  /opt/gopath/src/github.com/dorzheh/deployer/example/myproduct/ /home/vagrant/example
cd /home/vagrant/
go build  /home/vagrant/example/deployer/deployer.go
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at https://github.com/weldpua2008/deployer, it does have a `deployer` directory at the root. When you issue `go build  example/myproduct/deployer/deployer.go` it tries to create a file called `deployer` but fails because the directory already exists.